# PHP Regex function to find and replace words from string

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have movie titles and I want to remove everything after the "empty space" before the word "DVD" or Bluray begins.
So for example I have the following strings

```
Avatar DVD 2009
War of the Roses DVD 1989 Region 1 US import
Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import
```

Output

```
=====
Avatar
War of the Roses

=======
```

Comment: Why is `Wanted` deleted?

Comment: Is the list of movies all in one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want a regex (including the `strripos()` following xzyfer comment):

```
<?php 

function stripTypeTitle($title) {
    $dvdpos = strripos($title, 'dvd');
    $bluraypos = strripos($title, 'bluray');
    if ($dvdpos !== false && $dvdpos > $bluraypos) {
        $title = substr($title, 0, $dvdpos);
    }
    if ($bluraypos !== false && $bluraypos > $dvdpos) {
        $title = substr($title, 0, $bluraypos);
    }
    return $title;
}

$title = "Avatar DVD 2009";
echo stripTypeTitle($title)."<br/>";
$title = "War of the Roses DVD 1989 Region 1 US import";
echo stripTypeTitle($title)."<br/>";
$title = "Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import";
echo stripTypeTitle($title)."<br/>";
$title = "This Bluray is Wanted DVD 2008 US Import";
echo stripTypeTitle($title)."<br/>";
$title = "This DVD is Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import";
echo stripTypeTitle($title)."<br/>";

?>
```

Prints:

```
Avatar
War of the Roses
Wanted
This Bluray is Wanted
This DVD is Wanted
```

Comment: In this case you'd want to match the space before and after the dvd or blueray keyword or else you'll get false positives i.e. `this is my dvd title blueray 2009` will result in `this is my `

Comment: In your example, maybe I could see using `strripos()`. However, your own example is a bit contradictory.

Comment: Also, you should use an `else if` rather than just `else` because an item can't be a DVD and a Blueray. Also will cause a different false positive i.e. `this is my blueray title dvd 2009` will return `this is my blueray` where as if you had an `else if` if would correct return ``this is my blueray title``

Comment: @jason, my example would also fail in my first case, I have updated it to account for that.

Comment: thanks, this works! nice script. i just edit it according to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = preg_replace('/ (DVD|BLURAY).*/i', '', $input);
```

Comment: @ricky: Matching them all? What do you mean?

Comment: @ricky, is the list of movies all in one string?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the command:

`preg_replace('( (DVD|Bluray).*$)', '', 'Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import')`

Basically, we select a space, the word "DVD" or the word "Bluray" then anything until then end of the string and replace it with nothing (thus remove them). Simply put this in the loop should work for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Keep it simple. You may want to add the `'i'` and `'m'` modifiers however.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** movie title list from Jason's answer

Try this (assuming the list of title is one string):

```
$titles = "Avatar DVD 2009
War of the Roses DVD 1989 Region 1 US import
Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import
This Bluray is Wanted DVD 2008 US Import
This DVD is Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import";

$filteredTitles = array_map(function($title) { 
    return preg_replace('/^(.+) ((?:DVD|Bluray) .+)$/', '$1', $source)
}, explode(PHP_EOL, $titles));

echo $filteredTitles; 

/*
Avatar
War of the Roses
Wanted Bluray 2008 US Import
This Bluray is Wanted
This DVD is Wanted
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$title = preg_replace('/ (DVD|Bluray) /',' ' ,$title);
```