# Is there an jQuery function that will just refresh a PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm new to AJAX, jQuery, etc.

But is there a function that will just auto-refresh a PHP script?

Comment: Could you give some more information on what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to execute a javascript function at regular intervals you cold use the [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this method will execute on every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

So you could write a function that will send an AJAX request to your PHP script:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // replace the contents of an element with id="res" 
    // every 5 seconds by the result of the PHP script
    $('#res').load('/foo.php');
}, 5000);
```

Or if you want to reload the entire page (without using AJAX) you could use `window.location.reload();`

Comment: I think this would be a more complete answer if it also showed how to setup a content update using `$.get()` and `setInterval()`. Hard to tell if that's what the poster meant, but at least it would cover that use case.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I showed this using the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to the punch... :) Except that, wouldn't it need to specify to the script only to return a portion of the HTML content? Not the entire page, per se?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, this would be possible as well: `$('#res').load('/foo.php #bar');` where `bar` is an id element from the resulting html that will only be injected instead of the entire result.

Comment: @Darin - I understand, but shouldn't that be in the answer?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I answer only concrete and specific questions. No such thing has been asked so I prefer not to put it as I have no idea what the OP is looking for and might not be something that is well adapted to hos scenario. There might even be a better way so until I have a clear understanding of the OP scenario I prefer to limit my answer to the strict minimum in order to cover the strict minimum he asked about.

Comment: @Darin - Depending on the details as well, that might probably be a better thing to send in a GET variable, IE, `foo.php?content=bar`

Comment: @Darin - Fair enough. However, I guess I would point out that the question itself is not "concrete and specific". :P

Comment: @Jared Farrish, absolutely, there are many things that are possible and better. It's just that we cannot propose them as we don't know what is needed so the word *better* is subjective at the moment. And I absolutely agree with you that the question is not concrete and specific.

Comment: @Darin - You are obviously not well-versed in the dark art of answering questions that have not been asked.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, no, I have to work on improving those skills.

Comment: @Darin - It's equal parts creative energy, carefree attitude and knowing "what they really meant". It helps if you are also inclined to storytelling.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, programming is an exact science, not storytelling.

Comment: @Darin - Sure sure (I've been joking mostly). In all seriousness, the way that people use or describe software needs is not so precise. Understanding intent can often be tangential, not linear. Your approach obviously works; but I come from the creative side, and it's a bit like herding cats; each user has it's own story. I need to work on being more like you, but you might consider my approach may also be helpful when the client isn't so capable of communicating meaning in structured contexts.

Comment: @Darin - This is a classic example of divining intent over description; I knew what the poster was needing, but the language was inexact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439772/php-regex-function-to-find-and-replace-words-from-string

Comment: @Jared Farrish, I absolutely agree with your approach towards the client. They shouldn't necessarily understand the technical aspects. But StackOverflow is not for clients. It is for software engineers asking questions about programming and when asking such questions [they should take certain things into consideration](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: @Darin - I quibble. When I say client, I mean the person posting the question; in this context, they are the client looking for a solution. There are obvious instances of non-technical users asking questions on SO (like this one). http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ was created, I thought, specifically for the software engineer needs you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, just plain old Javascript.

```
window.location.reload()
```

should reload the current page. Combine with `window.setTimeout` to do it after some delay if that's what you need.

See docs for:

- [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)
- [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.settimeout)